# AucTeX: Symbol's function definition is void: signum

Tags: auctex

recently I have updated auctex-11.89.5.
Then, I got Symbol's function definition is void: signum when I have some compile errors and go to the error by hitting C-c `.

I don't know about lisp code and need some help to tackle this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the report.  Try adding this line at the beginning of your init file as a workaround: `(require 'cl)`. I'll need to fix this, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error was due to a recent change introduced in AUCTeX (to fix another bug [reported](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/26461/620) in StackExchange network).  It has been now fixed upstream, as a temporary fix you can add this line to the beginning of your init file:

```lisp
(require 'cl)
```

However, please note that in version 11.88 of AUCTeX has been introduced a nicely formatted list of errors and warnings that can be accessed with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-error-overview` <kbd>RET</kbd>, or from the menu `Command` → `Error Overview`.  You can navigate between errors with <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>, so you can forget about <kbd>C-c `</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The TeX-error-overview is awesome.